# MySql Function Select Syntax

Tags: mysql

IN Microsoft SQL Server we will do like this

```
SELECT *,AA=dbo.GET_Date()   
 FROM _profilesearch p
```

--- n this is function we will call from select list

How to do same in MySQL npls

```
SELECT Get_Date() AS gid;

SELECT *,AA=SELECT ' GET_Date'
 FROM _profilesearch p LIMIT 0,30;
```

Comment: What is "--- n this is function we will call from select list"?
What is "npls"?
What is the 2nd piece / segment of SQL? Are you asking something about it? Question is very unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, Now() as AA
FROM _profilesearch
```